# Want to convert ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> to string

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist, universal-image-loader

I read the [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/UniversalImageLoaderExample/src/com/nostra13/example/universalimageloader/ImageGridActivity.java) and I make application that has gridview and this gridview get image from json. but my application load so slow, so I want to use Universal Image Loader but `getView` function in Universal Image Loader in ImageAdapeter class it use like that

`imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[position], imageView, options);` or for formula 
`imageLoader.displayImage(String, imageView, options);`

So I don't have a string to complete this formula. I just can create `Object arr` to store Arraylist.

How can I convert `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>` to string or any ways to change my code?

Please confirm or advice or recommend me as you can. easy to read [my code](http://pastie.org/5620242)

Below this is my ImageAdapter. it work fine but so slow.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> MyArr = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

    public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> myArrList) {
        context = c;
        MyArr = myArrList;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return MyArr.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
        }
        viewHolder.categoryCard = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_card);
        //==================== change area
        Object arr = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>(); // make objec arr to store arraylist
        arr = MyArr.get(position).get("categoryid");
        if (arr.equals("1")) {
            viewHolder.categoryCard.setImageResource(R.drawable.card_eat);
            viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        } else {
            viewHolder.categoryCard.setImageResource(R.drawable.card_etc);
            viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        }
        // =============================
        try {
            viewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) MyArr.get(position).get("ImageThumBitmap"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image);
        }

        return convertView;

    }

}


// Download JSON in Background
public class DownloadJSONFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    String token = getIntent().getExtras().getString("token1");

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_JSON_PROGRESS);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        String url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/card/all/20/0/?token="+token;
        JSONArray data = null;
        try {

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(getJSONUrl(url));

            MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
            HashMap<String, Object> map;
            data = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
                map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                // Thumbnail Get ImageBitmap To Object
                map.put("cardimage", (String) c.getString("cardimage"));
                map.put("ImageThumBitmap",(Bitmap) loadBitmap(c.getString("cardimage")));
                map.put("categoryid", (String) c.getString("categoryid"));
                MyArrList.add(map);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        ShowAllContent(); // When Finish Show Content
        dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_JSON_PROGRESS);
        removeDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_JSON_PROGRESS);
    }

}
```

This is ImageAdapter that come from [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/UniversalImageLoaderExample/src/com/nostra13/example/universalimageloader/ImageGridActivity.java)

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageUrls.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = (ImageView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_grid_image, parent, false);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
                     // I want to do like this
        imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[position], imageView, options);

        return imageView;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) You are having `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>`, right? 2) Does every HashMap contain Image URL?

Comment: it content like this `MyArr.get(position).get("categoryid")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to keep the `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>` you have to create a new `String[]` this way:

```
String[] urls = new String[MyArrList.size()];
for(int i=0; i<MyArrList.size(); i++){
   urls[i] = MyArrList.get(i).get("cardimage");
}
```

PS. I've used the variable name MyArrList as you declared in your code, by the way it's not a good idea to start a variable name with a capital letter.

PS2. I think that if you want to use the Universal Image Loader you'll maybe no longer need to store each Bitmap in the HashMap

Comment: How can I change all of this code. I want to change it so much. I want to improve it faster. http://pastie.org/5620383

Answer (score 1):

In your `DownloadJSONFileAsync Class` which you [posted here](http://pastie.org/5620242) ,

1. You have not downloaded the JSON. So your variable `JSONArray data` will always be null.
2. On `Line 33` need not use a `new ArrayList` you need to access the ArrayList which you stored in `DownloadJSONFileAsync Class`. Find updated code below.

   ```
   public class DownloadJSONFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

   String token = getIntent().getExtras().getString("token1");
   JSONObject response = null;

   protected void onPreExecute() {
       super.onPreExecute();
       showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_JSON_PROGRESS);
   }

   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

       String url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/card/all/20/0/?token="+token;
       JSONArray response = //YOUR JSON ARRAY AFTER DOWNLOADING;
       return null;
   }

   protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
       ShowAllContent(JSONArray); // When Finish Show Content and send the Response JSONARRAY and display the content on the GridView
       dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_JSON_PROGRESS);
       removeDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_JSON_PROGRESS);
   }}
   ```

Your ShowAllContent(JSONArray jsonVal) Code

```
public void ShowAllContent(JSONArray jsonVal) {

    gridView1 = (ScrollableGridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_all);
    gridView1.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(CardActivity.this, jsonVal));
    gridView1.setExpanded(true);
    gridView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
        }
    });

    gridView1.setOnScrollListener(new PauseOnScrollListener(true, true));

}
```

In your `getView() method of ImageAdapter` use the below line.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    public ImageAdapter(Context c, JSONArray jsonArray) {
        context = c;
        this.jsonArray = jsonArray;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return jsonArray.length();
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //DO YOUR CODE HERE
       imageLoader.displayImage(jsonArray[position].get("ImageThumBitmap").toString(), imageView, options);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't add JSONArray to ShowAllContent. Please See [Full Source](http://pastie.org/5620350). Please help me change a little bit